# Let VMware keep focus when mouse is outside of window

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-player

I'm using VMware player 16 on win10. As soon as my mouse moves outside of the VM I can no longer type in the VM. My expectation is that I should have to click on another window before I can no longer type in the VM.

If I move the mouse outside of the window I can no longer type, but once the mouse moves back inside of the window I can type again.

Can anyone advise on how to retain the ability to type when the cursor is outside of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is entirely normal and the way VMware Workstation AND Player both work.

This is isolation between machines and VMware tools make it easy to move between machines without having to use Ctrl-Alt to change machines. A virtual machine is not a regular app window.

So this is working as designed. I am in VMware now and as noted, this is how machine isolation works. So VMware will not keep mouse focus (or keyboard focus) outside the virtual machine window.

You can try variations of the Hot Key settings to see if that will approximate what you are trying to do.

[image]

Comment: I get that it's normal, I'm trying to find a way around it. I don't need my vm to be isolated from the host. What I'm actually trying to do is be able to use my scroll wheel in a web browser outside of the VM or inside of a second VM. I'm new to VMware, this was easy to accomplish with parallels on MacOS.

Comment: You cannot get around the machine isolation. Otherwise the machines might lose control of the mouse. So it must be used as designed. You also cannot have a separate virtual machine that works like a window. So you cannot work the way you wish.

Comment: You can try variations of Hot Key settings to see if they will assist what you are trying to do. This is from VMware Workstation, but Player should have Hot Key settings.